# Babel sublime throwing errors

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, babeljs

I have the following `ReactJS` code:

```
render() {
        return (
            <ValidatorForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <TextValidator
                    floatingLabelText="Password"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    validators={['required']}
                    errorMessages={['this field is required']}
                    value={user.password}
                />
                <TextValidator
                    floatingLabelText="Repeat password"
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                    name="repeatPassword"
                    type="password"
                    validators={['isPasswordMatch', 'required']}
                    errorMessages={['password mismatch', 'this field is required']}
                    value={user.repeatPassword}
                />
                <RaisedButton type="submit" />
            </ValidatorForm>
        );
    }
```

When I try `Babel Transform` within Sublime I get the following error:

```
Error: SyntaxErrorD:/web dev/repos/myRepo/client/src/Modules/Register.js: Unexpected token (81:12)

  79 |     render() {
  80 |         return (
> 81 |             <ValidatorForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     |             ^
  82 |                 <TextValidator
  83 |                     floatingLabelText="Password"
  84 |                     onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Has anyone else seen this? I'm having a horrible time trying to find an IDE that does everything in a React way - tried Webstorm, Atom, VSCode etc but would like to stick with Sublime if possible.

Comment: This seems like a config problem. Your file is probably not even recognized as a react file. Try to change the extension to `.jsx`.

Comment: Nope, changed it to `.jsx` - same error